# How to determine TypeDeclaration is a class?(TypeDeclaration cannot be converted to Class)

Tags: java

I want to get all class names in .java file.But i can't determine TypeDeclaration is a class or something.
I try to use following code snippet and I get error

```
    if (type instanceof Class))
    {return packagePrefix + type.getName();}
```

Error:TypeDeclaration cannot be converted to Class

Full Code:

```
public static String parseClassname(File filename) throws Exception {
    try (FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(filename)) {
        CompilationUnit cu = JavaParser.parse(fin);
        String packagePrefix = cu.getPackage().getName().toString();
        if (!packagePrefix.isEmpty()) packagePrefix += ".";

        for (TypeDeclaration type : cu.getTypes())
        {
            if (type instanceof Class)) ////
            {return packagePrefix + type.getName();}      

        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Class` is part of Java reflection API for representing types at run-time. If you would like to get the first `class` declaration from the source, you should use [`ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration`](http://static.javadoc.io/com.github.javaparser/javaparser-core/2.5.1/com/github/javaparser/ast/body/ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration.html) with Java parser, and check that `isInterface` is `false`:

```
if (!(type instanceof ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration))) {
    continue;
}
ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration classOrInterface = (ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration)type;
if (!classOrInterface.isInterface()) {
    return packagePrefix + type.getName();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`cu.getTypes` returns instances `TypeDeclaration`, that's why you get the error. I'm not familiar with that library but if I understand the JavaDoc correctly checking the single instance to be an instance of `ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration` should be the way to go. So instead of

```
if (type instanceof Class))
```

you might try

```
if (type instanceof ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration))
```